# React Native - Scrollview scrolls up with many inputs [iOS]

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, touchableopacity

I have many inputs within ScrollView. Everytime I try to tap the **Save button**, if the last input focused is out of the screen view (where the Save button is), the screen scrolls automatically up to the input. However, if I scroll down again and press/tap the Save button again, it works. So I have to **tap twice the button**.

This only happens on **iOS devices**. On Android works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
 render() {
    const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 40 : 0;

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : ""}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: colors.white,
          }}
        >
          <ScrollView
            ref={(scroll) => (this.scroll = scroll)}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
            style={{
              marginBottom: this.state.marginBottom,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
            }}
          >
            <DateForm
              onChangeDate={this.onChangeDate.bind(this)}
              date={this.state.measureDate}
              birthdate={this.state.baby.Birthdate}
            />
            <MeasureForm
              onChangeMeasure={this.onChangeValue.bind(this)}
              value={this.state.value}
              scrollTo={this.scrollTo.bind(this)}
            />
            <ResultsForm
              IC={this.state.indexes.IC}
              IABC={this.state.indexes.IABC}
              colorIC={this.state.indexes.colorIC}
              colorIABC={this.state.indexes.colorIABC}
            />

            <CBButton
              title={global.loc.getTranslation("AddMeasureSaveButton")}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                marginHorizontal: 0,
                flexGrow: 1,
                marginTop: 20,
                marginBottom: 50,
              }}
              disabled={!this.state.validForm}
              onPress={() => this.disableButton()}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

**UPDATE**

[Here is a minimal reproducible example on snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@4alifetime/focus-issue-on-ios)

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? Perhaps on Snack?

Comment: @jnpdx here I sort of reproduced the issue with a [snack code example](https://snack.expo.dev/@4alifetime/focus-issue-on-ios) . If you simulate it on iOS, focus on the **first input**, then scroll down to the **save button**, and try to tap it. You will be scrolled all the way up.

Comment: I've just found [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30736) that talks about it!